# How can I get different images to fit in the same 'box'?

Tags: html, css, image, position, width

How can I make sure that the images always are on the 'same' width and height, so they are matched in terms of those two? Now the second one is much larger and the boxes don't match up anymore. I need to get a big list with images that I got from someone, and they are not all the same dimensions sadly. **The images need to be scaled proportionally**

```css
.slider-item {
  width: 50%;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
.slider-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.text {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-item">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Shaqi_jrvej.jpg/1200px-Shaqi_jrvej.jpg" alt="product">
   <div class="text">
      <h3>123</h3>
      <h4>23</h4>
      <h2>Bonte</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <a href="">Order</a>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-item">
   <img src="https://pi.tedcdn.com/r/talkstar-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/production/playlists/playlist_398/reconnect_with_nature.jpg" alt="product">
   <div class="text">
      <h3>123</h3>
      <h4>23</h4>
      <h2>Bonte</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <a href="">Order</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `height` and a `width` to the images. Then apply the `object-fit: cover` CSS rule on them.

> The object-fit CSS property sets how the content of a replaced
> element, such as an  or , should be resized to fit its
> container.

Possible values: *contain*, *cover*, *fill*, *none*, *scale-down*

```css
.slider-item {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.slider-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-item">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Shaqi_jrvej.jpg/1200px-Shaqi_jrvej.jpg" alt="product">
  <div class="text">
    <h3>123</h3>
    <h4>23</h4>
    <h2>Bonte</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <a href="">Order</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-item">
  <img src="https://pi.tedcdn.com/r/talkstar-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/production/playlists/playlist_398/reconnect_with_nature.jpg" alt="product">
  <div class="text">
    <h3>123</h3>
    <h4>23</h4>
    <h2>Bonte</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <a href="">Order</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lifesaver! I didn't know about the object-fit: cover; rule. I only thought that stuff like that was possible on 'background-images' in css.

Comment: The height: 10rem; is just random right? Theres no particular reason for the rem instead of px usage right?

Comment: Yes, it is random. Just choose what works best for you.